# Express array of routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

The [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#path-examples) says that you can supply an array for the path variable in app.use(). I'm trying to have all routes in the routes array point back to the static folder in the static variable.
Here's what I have:

```
const static = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build'));
const routes = ['/','/projects','/project1','/blog']
app.use(routes, static);
```

These routes all do work correctly with the static folder variable if I write a seperate app.use() function for each route, but it would be a lot more maintainable if I can get the routes in an array like in the documentation. The documentation doesn't show any examples suggesting that I need to map through the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it appears (based on experimentation as this is not in the doc), that when you pass an array of routes, Express finds the first item in the array that matches the current path and calls the route handler for that one only.  Even if there are other routes that would also match (as in your case), it does not call the route handler again for those.

So, because `'/'` matches ALL routes when used with `app.use()`, it will always use that one and thus the others will never work properly when using the array, but do work properly when listed as individual routes.  You can fix it by making sure that the most permissive routes are last.  So, change your array to this:

```
const static = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build'));
const routes = ['/projects','/project1','/blog', '/'];
app.use(routes, static);
```

This moves `'/'` to the end so the others get a chance to match before the `'/'` is looked at and .  `'/'` will only get used when the path wasn't one of the others.

---

FYI, this is a bit of a weird structure where you're directing multiple URL path prefixes all to the same `../build` directory for `express.static()` to look there.  There's no reason you need to do it that way.  This appears to be an artificially created issue because of your URL design.  Doing it this way will cause URLs like `/x.js`, `/projects/x.js` and `/blog/x.js` to resolve to the exact same `x.js` file in the `../build` directory.

Comment: I'm making a react app served from a static folder with react router for client side urls. If you refresh the page, the server doesn't know what to do with it. This points all routes back to the static folder for react router to handle and fix the page refresh issue.

Comment: @Shawn - I have no idea what that comment means at all.  I answered what you asked in your question exactly and precisely and even verified that it works by testing it.  If you have some other question related to your React app, then perhaps you should open a new question.

Comment: from your answer: "Im not sure why you're doing this". I explained why I'm doing it. I didn't ask any other questions.

Comment: @Shawn - If you have a page refresh issue that somehow requires pointing at four different static directories for the same files, then you probably have a different problem in your static react app because that should not be necessary.  That could be the subject of another question if you wanted.